# im getting this error while creating fake factory model data in Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

\App\Models\Testt::factory()->create();
PHP Error:  Class "Database\Factories\TesttFactory" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory.php on line 683

im using cmd and using migrations to generate fake data
below is the mentioned code of factory, migrations

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Testt;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

**class TesttfactoryFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = \App\Models\Testt::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}**
```

and for migrations the code is

```
**<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class CreateTesttsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('\App\Models\testts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->mediumText('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('testts');
    }
}**
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: please checkout i ve added the links